# Add voices in Festival tts

Tags: raspberry-pi, text-to-speech, raspbian, festival

So I am trying to use festival tts on my raspberry pi for a smart home project. However, when I try to use a british english voice it says not a british english voice installed.

```
echo "hello world" | festival --tts --language "british_english"
Not a british English voice installed
```

But if I put in a made up language it says that one of the available language it says that British english is installed.

```
echo "hello world" | festival --tts --language "madeuplanguage"
"Language not installed. The installed languages are:"
(russian american_english finnish welsh italian english british_english czech scots_gaelic castillian_spanish)
```

The voice I want is this [here](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/onlinedemo.html) the one I want is the "[peter, english rp male]" because it is the most natural sounding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed languages and installed voices are different. You might have a language installed but no voice installed. The british voice you mention is commercial and probably not available in public.

If you want good tts on RPI, you'd better use something like online Google TTS (should be free for small amount of texts) or Amazon TTS. You can also consider any Tacotron voice, like Nvidia tacotron, but again you will not be able to run it on Raspberry Pi, you will need a server.